# React js fetch API with componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React.js and trying to fetch API with fetch() and I tried to use componentDidMount() but I have a problem, you can see the pic at the end of the post.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'


export default class App extends Component {
    
    state = {
      weather: []
    };
    
    
    fetchData() {
        fetch('prevision-meteo.ch/services/json/rochelle-17')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((obj) => {
            console.log('javascript object: ', obj)
            this.setState({ weather: obj.results});
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
          })
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('Le composant App est monté sur le DOM !')
        this.fetchData();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.weather&& this.state.weather.map((weatherRecord) => ( 
                  <div key={weatherRecord.city_info.name}>{weatherRecord.city_info.name}</div>
                 ))}
                Hello World !
                <button /*onClick={() => this.fetchData()}*/> Click me</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I want to get the name of city_info in my page but didn't work!

This is the results in the console, can anyone help me?
[image]

Comment: The error is telling you that `obj.results` is `undefined`. Your best bet is to use the debugger built into your browser to set a breakpoint on the `this.setState()` line and look at what `obj` is. Apparently it doesn't have a `results` property.

Comment: Side note: It's not the problem, but that code is susceptible to the `fetch` footgun I describe in [this post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) on my anemic little blog.

Comment: Also consider using `weather`, not `wheather`, misspelled words are an easy source of frustrating bugs

Comment: but when i use console.log('javascript object: ', obj),i caan see the content of json in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      wheather: null
    };
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/rochelle-17.json")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((obj) => {
        //console.log('javascript object: ', obj)
        this.setState({ wheather: obj });
      });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Le composant App est monté sur le DOM !");
    this.fetchData();
  }
 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.wheather
          && <div key={this.state.wheather.city_info.name}>{this.state.wheather.city_info.name}</div>
        }
        Hello World !
        <button /*onClick={() => this.fetchData()}*/> Click me !</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank u for ur help, the error was fixed but the problem now that's i can't get the name from json file!

Comment: That's a different issue then. Please check your 'obj.result' and structure of it. Or you can provide that JSON details here.

Comment: this is my JSON file : https://www.prevision-meteo.ch/services/json/rochelle-17
how can i get the infos frome this??

Comment: Is it whole 'obj.results'? 'obj.results' is an Array or Object?

Comment: i don't know but i want to get the name of ctiy from this file JSON : prevision-meteo.ch/services/json/rochelle-17  using fetch! the 'obj.results' i get it from a video

Comment: If obj.results is an array and it contains objects as you shown in "prevision-meteo.ch/services/json/rochelle-17" then your code is fine. But if it is not, then you have to update your code. Check edited part of my post.

Comment: Updated first part too.

Comment: Do one thing uncomment this line and show me what is printed in console. //console.log('javascript object: ', obj)

Comment: can u see the pic now? i get the object but i can't display the name of info_city!

Answer (score 1):

Setting state is asynchronous so React is rendering before the state has been set. What you can do is put in a short circuit condition `this.state.weather &&` to check if the weather array exists and only when it is available will the `map` operation be performed and you shouldn't get any errors.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'


export default class App extends Component {
    
    state = {
      weather: []
    };
    
    
    fetchData() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/rochelle-17.json')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((obj) => {
            //console.log('javascript object: ', obj)
            this.setState({ weather: obj.results});
        })
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('Le composant App est monté sur le DOM !')
        this.fetchData();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.weather&& this.state.weather.map((weatherRecord) => (
                    <div key={weatherRecord.city_info.name}></div>
                ))}
                Hello World !
                <button /*onClick={() => this.fetchData()}*/> Click me</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Some Notes:**

- The newer versions of React support setting initial state like this, which is a bit cleaner:

  ```
   state = {
     weather: []
   }
  ```
- It's also good practice to catch errors in case the API call fails. You can simply use `.catch` like this after the last `.then()`:

  ```
   .catch((error) => {
     console.error(error)
   })
  ```
- Since ES6 you don't need to use `return` for the `<div>` you are rendering. You can simply use map with curved brackets `()` instead of curly brackets `{}` to implicitly return

  ```
   {this.state.weather&& this.state.weather.map((weatherRecord) => ( 
     <div key={weatherRecord.city_info.name}></div>
   ))}
  ```

Comment: thank u for ur help, the error was fixed but the problem now that's i can't get d name from json file!